# What http status codes should I set myself, and in what situations?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-status-codes

What http status codes should I set myself, and in what situations?

For instance, if the server receives a request to delete a non-existent entry from the database, should I return a 404 error code? Something else?

Comment: Since the request made is on a non-existent page/record...you can return a 404 in this case...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about designing a RESTful API, yes it makes sense to return a `404` status when you receive a request (`GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE`) to operate on a nonexistent entity.

Comment: This will probably make me sound quite ignorant, but what's a RESTful API?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services is a start

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on who the client is and what functionality you require. But I might warn against 404s, as they are so synonymous with operation failure. But this might be the right way to go in your case

Answer (score 0):

I should not return the `404` code because i thing that returning `404` most of time mean that the url doesn't exist or the page is not found when we are doing a `Get` request. But doing a `Delete` request, i would opt for a `400 Bad Request` with a message error (message can explain what wrong). I think that returning a `404` status can be confusing but Bad Request will tell the of the api the URL exist but he is doing something wrong.
It can be sometime frustrating if the consumer of the api does not understand very well the error that is happening. But If you do not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code `404 (Not Found)` can be used instead. 
Me i would return a `Bad Request` for internal part of the application but `Not Found` for Public/Consumer part of of an application.

[404 Not Found](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5)

> This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to
>   reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other
>   response is applicable.